# Callback called when a task finish OR already finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, asynchronous

I have a simple code that involves asynchronous tasks:

```
// The NewsFeed Class

function NewsFeed() {

    this.loadFeed = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.com",
            success: function() {
                // doSomething here, and call onload.
            }
        });
    }

    // Need to implement onload here somehow
    this.onload = ?;

    this.loadFeed();
    return this;

}
NewsFeed.constructor = NewsFeed;



// In main JS file
var newsFeed = new NewsFeed();
$(function() {
    // do something
    newsFeed.onload = function() { // do something when news feed is loaded };
}
```

My requirement is that, `onload` of NewsFeed needed to be executed in both case:

- If the loadFeed's ajax is finished, run it immediately.
- If the loadFeed's ajax is not done yet, run after it.

Comment: `this.loadFeed();` will throw an error. but anyway it sounds like you're describing what a promise does. It will execute a callback when done, and if you add another callback after it is done it will be called immediately with the result.

Comment: Thanks, it was by bad. It should be `this.loadFeed = function()`

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to use `new` or `constructor` when you don't need new instances, all you really need is to run a simple ajax function that gets the result from cache if it hasn't changed.

```
function newsFeed() {
   return $.ajax({
       url   : "http://www.example.com",
       cache : true // let the browser handle caching for you
   });
}


// In main JS file
$(function() {
    newsFeed().then(function() { 
        // do something when news feed is loaded 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The new pattern instead of callback is using Promises 
see:
https://github.com/kriskowal/q

With jquery you can use:
https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

now the code:

```html
function NewsFeed() {

    function loadFeed() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.com",
            success: function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    this.loadFeed = loadFeed;
    return this;

}
NewsFeed.constructor = NewsFeed;



// In main JS file
var newsFeed = new NewsFeed();
newsFeed.loadFeed().done(function(data){
  //data loaded successfully
})
.fail(function(data){
  //ajax request failed
})
.always(function(){
  //finally:
});
```

Comment: this is a very common anti-pattern... `$.ajax` already returns a promise, there is no need to create a new one

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it